# Magento 2 How to Add CMS Block to Email Confirmation Email

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email-templates, cms-block

In magento 1 we can add CMS blocks like this `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block"}}`, I've tried this in Magento 2 but does not work. Is there a way of adding a CMS into an email template? For instance `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html`

Comment: share you file path which you want to add block.

Comment: Do you have ask question about override order_new.html something ?

Comment: Just now you have post question about override email template, i have give answer but you have delete just now

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @André, Please describe your question. What you want ? And Also post some your codding issue.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Should create new custom theme

And then, copy the default email template to your custom theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html
```

### Add cms block to email template

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" area='frontend' block_id="my_block"}}
```

We can see more:

`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new_guest.html`

Comment: working fine! thanks